# How do I call the Win32 API version of a function from an MFC application?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

Specifically, I created a console with `AllocConsole()`. Now I want to take that window and move it.

First I want to call `GetWindowRect` to get its width and height. But if I just type that in it calls the implementation in `CWnd`. I need to call the one that accepts a `HWND` as the first parameter.

How do I do this?

Comment: I'm making assumptions here, but `::GetWindowRect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix the function name by the <del>namespace operator</del> scope resolution operator when you call it. This will prevent the CWnd member function from being a match.

```
void MyWindow::foo()
{
    HWND wnd; // = ...
    CRect rect;
    ::GetWindowRect(wnd, &rect);
}
```

Comment: The term you're looking for is "scope resolution operator", particularly the unary variety.

Comment: Don't take the address of a `CRect` when passing it to a Windows API function that expects an `LPRECT`. Use `operator LPRECT()` instead, i.e. `::GetWindowRect(wnd, rect);`.

Comment: @IInspectable Why? I don't see any advantage.

Comment: Passing `&rect` assumes a particular implementation of `CRect` that can change at any time. Using the provided conversion operator does not rely on a specific binary layout.

Comment: @IInspectable Last time I checked CRect publicly inherits from RECT. That's hardly an implementation detail.

Comment: Calling an implementation detail not an implementation detail is something I am hard pressed to comprehend.